# Why not adding $scope can work?

Tags: angularjs

In directive, why we do not add $scope as prefix in `customer.name` can work? I change to `$scope.customer.name`, it cannot work? Why? It suppose to have $scope, correct? Link (https://plnkr.co/edit/e4N2u1iuXbp7IESxNd1T?p=preview)

```
angular.module('docsSimpleDirective', [])
.controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.customer = {
    name: 'Naomi',
    address: '1600 Amphitheatre'
  };
}])
.directive('myCustomer', function() {
  return {
    template: 'Name: {{customer.name}} Address: {{customer.address}}'
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever you assign to `template` is equivalent to an HTML page with the body holding the content you assigned. Don't confuse it with the code inside the angular js controller. It is rather an HTML response in the form of a string, and we do not use `$scope` inside an HTML document.

Comment: I got. Can you send me reference document about it? Thanks

Comment: @AngularJS the meaning of template is consistent throughout web, irrespective of what language you choose to write code. I suggest you should read what a template is. However, [here](https://www.3pillarglobal.com/insights/angularjs-understanding-custom-directive) lies the meaning of template in clear words.